# How to change default maps to Google Maps for WhatsApp location sharing on iPhone 7?

Tags: iphone, ios, whatsapp.app, google-maps

How to change default maps to Google maps on iPhone 7 while sharing location to others on WhatsApp Application ?

iOS Version : 11.1.2,
Model : iPhone 7, 128 GB

I also tried uninstalling Apple Maps, but no use !

Comment: I do not believe it is possible to change *ANY* default apps on any version of IOS outside of jailbreaking

Answer (score 1):

Hold down the location and copy it to your clipboard and paste it on hangouts app chat and click on that it will redirect it to google maps if the original sender sent the location via google maps